# How should I change my loss function in case of regression in tensorflow if I have network which is initially designed for classification?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a pre-trained alexnet designed for classification task. 
Now I want to change that model for regression task.

What change should I make in the loss function in the below code in tensorflow? Now as it's regression, I don't have label but a vector of output.

```
with tf.name_scope("cross_ent"):
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = score, labels = y))
```

Also, anything else I should take care of while converting the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last layer of a classification network is usually a softmax layer, coupled with a loss that works well with the types of outputs of a softmax (a vector of probabilities summing to 1).

To perform regression, you will want a linear activation function at the last layer; and you could try a MSE (mean squared error) loss function between your target and your prediction.

Comment: Yes! I incorporated that using -  with tf.name_scope("cross_ent"):
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(score, y))

Comment: @Florentine Hennecker I am not getting correct regression values, not even close. I think somewhere in the model I am squeezing or normalizing the data. Any idea, I am using AlexNet.

Comment: Are you sure your last layer's activation function is linear? What's the range of values you're getting?

Comment: So, my ground truth vector has six elements (2 coordinates (range - 0 to 256px), 2 length measures (range - 20 to 60px), 1 sine value, 1 cosine value). Now sine and cosine values should be in the range of (-1 to 1). These ground truth values. Now, my for output my getting similar range for first 4 output but for sine and cosine, I getting values out of (-1 to 1). I am not really sure if the first 4 four coordinates are correct or not but they are in the range. Now, how should make sure my output range is correct? Especially in case of sine and cosine

Comment: This is how my last layer and error function looks like     **self.fc8 = fc(dropout7, 4096, self.NUM_CLASSES, relu = False, name='fc8')** and **with tf.name_scope("cross_ent"):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(score, y))**. NUM_CLASSES = 6. (my output vector)